# optimise angular duplicate code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

How can i optimise the duplicate code here

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('LogsController', function ($scope, LogsService) {
        $scope.updatingLogs = true;
        $scope.loggers = {};

        LogsService.findAll().$promise.then(function(data) {
            $scope.loggers = data;
            $scope.updatingLogs = false;
        });

        $scope.changeLevel = function (name, level) {
            LogsService.changeLevel({name: name, level: level}, function () {
                $scope.updatingLogs = true;
                LogsService.findAll().$promise.then(function(data) {
                    $scope.loggers = data;
                    $scope.updatingLogs = false;
                });
            });
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do create `$scope.findAll` method which will make an ajax of `LogsService.findAll()` so that you could be utilize this function while doing it multiple times from elsewhere.Optimize version would be.

**Code**

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('LogsController', function($scope, LogsService) {
        $scope.updatingLogs = true;
        $scope.loggers = {};

        $scope.findAll = function() {
            LogsService.findAll().$promise.then(function(data) {
                $scope.loggers = data;
                $scope.updatingLogs = false;
            });
        }

        $scope.changeLevel = function(name, level) {
            LogsService.changeLevel({
                name: name,
                level: level
            }, function() {
                $scope.updatingLogs = true;
                $scope.findAll();
            });
        };

        $scope.findAll(); //init
    });
```

Comment: this is really close to what I was about to say. The difference was that findAll() wasn't in $scope, unless the view needed to call it directly.

Comment: @fractalspawn ya..i added it in $scope because either way we can initialize it using `ng-init` which would make more sense as per unit testing perspective

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('LogsController', function ($scope, LogsService) {
        $scope.updatingLogs;
        $scope.loggers = LogsService.findAll();

        $scope.changeLevel = function (name, level) {
            $scope.updatingLogs = LogsService.changeLevel({name: name, level: level}, function () {
                LogsService.findAll().$promise.then(function(data) {
                    $scope.loggers = data;
                    $scope.updatingLogs = null;
                });
            });
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you're reaching for. If you're looking for code clarity, a potential refactor might look something like this.

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('LogsController', function ($scope, LogsService) {

    activate();

    $scope.changeLevel = function (name, level) {
        LogsService.changeLevel({name: name, level: level}, changelevelHandler);
    }; 

    function changeLevelHandler() {
        $scope.updatingLogs = true;
        getLogs();
    }

    function getLogs() {
      LogsService.findAll().$promise.then(function(data) {updateLoggers(data);});
    }

    function updateLoggers(data) {
        $scope.loggers = data;
        $scope.updatingLogs = false;
    }

    function activate() {
       $scope.updatingLogs = true;
       $scope.loggers = {};
       getLogs();

    }
});
```